# Read input without specifying input length

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, system-calls, armv7

I am trying to make the user input with any length.

More specifically, I am trying to read from input a directory that will be created using a `mkdir` syscall (`0x27`). But since this specificity is only for `mkdir`; you can also include for an issue for my program "creating directories"; I have multiple programs that act like this.

Without C libraries would be appreciated.

I tried

```
mov r7, #0x04
mov r0, #0x00
ldr r1, =some_variable
mov r2, #(1 << 30)
swi 0x00
```

but it works (on a terminated string); However, I would like to know other ways of approaching this.

Comment: You mean read directory entries, like with a getdents Linux system call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)?  The system call takes a size; you can pass a large size but it would make no sense to have an API that couldn't specify the size of the buffer user-space has already allocated.

Comment: Or do you want to read a string, and use that name for mkdir?  Again, it would make no sense for you to not tell `read` the limit of your buffer.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html.  What kind of thing are you hoping will happen?  Like that one system call will allocate memory for you *and* put input into it?  If you were reading from a pipe or socket, `splice(2)` I think at one point tried to let you do that (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html), but it's much less simple than `read`.  And I don't think it actually is possible given the docs for `SPLICE_F_MOVE`

Comment: A bit of a blindfold post, edited.

Comment: Oh nevermind I was thinking of the "allocating" part not the length part:  splice / [vmsplice](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vmsplice.2.html) do need a length.  And it seems you can't get the kernel to give you pages, only the reverse where you gift pages to the kernel with vmsplice when writing to a pipe.

Comment: What exact downside of the normal `read` system-call interface are you hoping to avoid?  Are you hoping to know what length to expect before you read?  Or hoping to avoid allocating a buffer at all?  Or what?  Because no, the Linux system-call API has no equivalent for `cin >> mystring` to allocate new memory with your data in it, in one system call.

Comment: In that case, what are some other approaches to this problem? (not involving C libraries)

Comment: To what problem?  Reading input in general isn't normally a problem.  Allocate a buffer of some reasonable size, like PATH_MAX in this case, and read() into it.  If read returns the buffer size, there might well be even more to read.

Comment: To what size? I am trying for maximum length. But also count the length for that input. (This is unrelated to `mkdir` but I like it to be on my other programs.)

Comment: An input stream (e.g. network socket or disk file) might have more than 4GiB of data available to read, so there's no way memory could contain that much data.  And you have to give it a buffer, which will have some max length, so you pass that as the length arg to `read`.  `read` tells you how much it read (as the return value) so you know if it filled the buffer you gave it or not.

Comment: Apparently `cin >> mystring;` takes an input of `1024` bytes and I checked it via `strace`. The unix command `cat` takes an input of `131072` bytes and repeating until End-of-File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you don't know the length but want to read all the data, you will have to read in chunks.  Chunk size can be whatever you want, as little as 1 byte and as much as you like.

Some data structures do not lend themselves to this kind of chunking, so for them, we need strategies to combine chunks from fixed sized reads into units that can be processed.  Variable length records (e.g. lines of text) might fall into this category, where occasionally the length of a line exceeds the fixed chunk size, but the processing algorithm want to see whole lines.

Sometimes we have to combine all the chunks into one single buffer for further processing.  Rather than allocating the largest possible buffer in the first place, that most likely would use dynamic memory allocation and memory copy to present that contiguous buffer of data in the end.

Exceedingly large data sets may require special handling, such as using a 64-bit computer.  Memory mapping files is also an option that can remove some of the buffering at the application level, in favor of letting the system do that.

The above applies whether writing in C or assembly.